# How can i create a complex Button shape?

Tags: java, image, swing, button, paintcomponent

I have a frame with an image covering it, And i want that every time some one clicks on a different object in the image , it will act as a button and do something.
The problem is , Is that those objects are not simple shapes, so  i was thinking about  drawing my own invisible buttons in the shape of those objects.

Is that possible? or what would be a better way to accomplish such a thing?

-thank you

Comment: Will be following this. I attempting something very similar on android a while back and ended up settling for just invisible buttons over the odd shapes :)

Comment: it will act as a button and do something. is for example something like as virtual remote for TV

Comment: See also the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/230513).

Answer (score 3):

**Concept: invisible buttons with circular and polygonal dispatch areas**

First, you'll want a class defining an invisible button, extending `javax.swing.AbstractButton` so that it's still a fully functional button that you can add listeners to.

```
public abstract class InvisibleButton extends AbstractButton {

    public abstract boolean contains(Point point);

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, of course, you'll want implementations of that class. Here's two examples: one using a polygon for complex shapes, one using a circle.

```
public class PolygonalButton extends InvisibleButton {

    private Polygon area = null;

    public PolygonalButton(Polygon area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point point) {
        return area.contains(point);
    }
}

public class CircularButton extends InvisibleButton {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private double radius;

    public CircularButton(int x, int y, double radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point point) {
        double dx = x - point.x;
        double dy = y - point.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= radius;
    }
}
```

Finally, you'll need to implement a container that handles all of these buttons, but you should use a panel instead of a frame.  Rather than hook each individual listener, you can simply override the frame's event processors and pass them to the necessary buttons.

```
public class InvisibleButtonImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private List<InvisibleButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    public InvisibleButtonImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void add(InvisibleButton button) {
        buttons.add(button);
    }

    public void remove(InvisibleButton button) {
        buttons.remove(button);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        for (InvisibleButton button : buttons) {
            if (button.isFocusOwner()) {
                button.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
        super.processKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent event) {
        for (InvisibleButton button : buttons) {
            if (button.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                button.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
        super.processMouseEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to rename the panel to something less bulky, and maybe implement your own advanced image code, but that's the basic idea behind it.

Comment: Good answer, though I'd warn the OP against using java.awt components in favor of Swing.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that the question was tagged with `swing`. I'll rewrite this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you track the users mouse position via Coordinates?

```
 PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b  = a.getLocation();
        int x = (int)b.getX();
        int y = (int)b.getY();
```

Now put a ActionPerformed Method and test if x and y = e.g. 200, 300 *do this*. That way when a user clicks on a spot (your aiming for area) it will redirect him to a method.

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface for a region like:

```
//represents any clickable area.
public interface IButton{
    boolean contains(int x, int y);
}
```

Then, if you want a circular area to be clickable, define a class which checks if a x,y coordinate is within some distance of a position.

```
public class CircleButton implements IButton{
    Point center;
    double radius;   
    public CircleButton(int x, int y, double radius){
        this.center = new Point(x,y);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    //check if x,y coords are within a radius 
    //from the center of this circle button
    public boolean contains(int x, int y){
        double dx = x-center.x;
        double dy = y-center.y;
        return (Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= radius);
    }
}
```

Create a list of IButtons. You'll iterate over these to see if a user clicked on one of your invisible buttons.

```
List<IButton> buttons = new List<IButton>();
buttons.add(new CircleButton(100,100,200);
```

Then each time someone clicks on your frame iterate over your invisible buttons using the location of that mouse click.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    for(IButton b : buttons){
       if(b.contains(evt.getX(),e.getY()){
           //do something depending on what button was clicked.
       }
    }
}
```

You can easily see how you could define invisible rectangle buttons like this, or even irregular polygon shapes. You'd just need to implement the `contains` method correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> And i want that every time some one clicks on a different object in the image , it will act as a button and do something.

You can create an ArrayList of `Shape` objects. Then you add a MouseListener to the component containing the image. Whenever a mousePressed event is generated you loop through the ArrayList and use the containts(...) method of the component to determine if the user click on a Shapes corrdinates.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). The code won't help with your immediate problem, but it will give you an idea of the type of `Shapes` that you can define.